# Amend parameter to include all information

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

I want to add this specific line of code to my ENDDATE parameter to verify a date range. I want to add this code

```
Set @ENDDATE = DateAdd(dd,1,@ENDDATE)
```

But im not sure where to put it, whenever in the report parameters query or not

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure too since you don't posted the query you want to be edited. To post Table definitions ill be a good idea too and a SQL Fiddle can be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it in your query:

```
SELECT SomeFields
FROM V_SubmissionDate
WHERE  (V_SubmissionDate.DATE_SUBMITTED >= @BEGINDATE) 
  AND (V_SubmissionDate.DATE_SUBMITTED <= DateAdd(dd,1,@ENDDATE)) 
  AND (APPLICATION.APP_DECISION_CODE <> 5)
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using a stored procedure. Here is the where statement in the stored procedure:
`WHERE  (V_SubmissionDate.DATE_SUBMITTED >= @BEGINDATE) AND (V_SubmissionDate.DATE_SUBMITTED <= @ENDDATE) AND (APPLICATION.APP_DECISION_CODE <> 5)`

Comment: Same thing, just use `DateAdd(dd,1,@ENDDATE)` instead of `@ENDDATE`. Answer updated.